# Having problems with questdlg in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm sorry for having only a part of the code but it is unnecessarily complicated. 
I want to have multiple question dialog boxes embedded with cases. The first switch case which is `switch secim` works fine when I put the last option twice which is `'Uc','Uc'` and unless I write it that way it shows only the other options. But when I do the same thing for the inner switch case which is`switch secim2` it gives an error on the line `secim2 = questdlg('İslem?', ...` and when I delete the second `'Birim vektor'` it works fine but doesn't show the Birim vektor option at all. How do I fix this?

```
secim = questdlg('Vektorler kac boyutlu?', ...
'Vektor', ...
'Bir','İki','Uc','Uc');
switch secim
case 'Bir'
    secim2 = questdlg('İslem?', ...
    'Vektor', ...,
    'Toplam','Fark','Skaler Carpim','Birim vektor');
switch secim2
...
```

Comment: [`questdlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/questdlg.html) only accepts up to 3 button options. Your first case has 4.

Comment: Is there an alternative I can use? I need 4 options.

Comment: See [`nbuttondlg`](https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/nbuttondlg) on GitHub. Disclaimer: I wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/questdlg.html), the syntax you're using in `secim` when you're repeating `'Uc'` is:

```
button = questdlg(qstring,title,str1,str2,str3,default)
```

As mentioned in the documentation, `default` should be one of `str1`, `str2` and `str3` and hence when you repeat `'Uc'`, it takes `'Uc'` as the default value and you have no problem.

In `secim2`, `'Birim vektor'` doesn't match any of the three strings and hence you'd get this warning:

> Warning: Default character vector does not match any button
>   character vector name.

If you repeat `'Birim vektor'`, it doesn't match with any of the [valid syntaxes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/questdlg.html).

<sup><sup>Above explanation is also pointed out in the comments.</sup></sup>

---

For more than three strings, use [`listdlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/listdlg.html).

```
choices = {'Toplam' ,'Fark','Skaler Carpim','Birim vektor'};
SelInd = listdlg('Name','Vektor', 'PromptString','İslem?','ListString',choices,...
    'CancelString', 'Default Choice', 'SelectionMode','single',...
    'ListSize',[200 100]) %adjust listsize as per requirement
SelInd(end+1) = 4;  %Default Choice (Biriam vektor)
secim2 = choices{SelInd(1)};
```

which gives:

[image: output]